# Target only fast Android devices in the Market

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-play

I've been looking for a way to only show my game to "fast enough" phones in the Market but I can't find any good answer.

Some people suggest to target by SDK, but that has nothing to do with the speed.

I've seen some to target by screen size, but some Acer phones and the HTC Legend are fast enough for my game but have the same screen than the HTC Hero which is pretty slow.

I also saw some people filtering by OpenGL ES version but I can't find any sort of database that tells me which phones have OpenGL ES 2. Android 2.0 is supposed to support it, but I don't know if phones like the HTC Magic, after being updated to 2.0 will support it or they will be stuck in 1.1.

What would be the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Why not warn the users that slow devices may result in poor performance?

Comment: You should not prevent your user from trying to run your apps in a slow device, just warn them of the potential performance problem. Desktop games does not prevent you from installing/running in a slow PC, some might warn about not meeting systems requirements, but I've seen none where you're intentionally blocked from installing/running.

Comment: Because people still install everything they can from the market and if doesn't work well they just blame the App.

Comment: Agreed, customers will complain even if they were specifically told it wouldn't work well on their phone.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people suggest to target by SDK, but that has nothing to do with the speed.

I would imagine any phone running Android 2.2 is fast enough for whatever you want to do.

> I also saw some people filtering by OpenGL ES version but I can't find any sort of database that tells me which phones have OpenGL ES 2.

You don't need a database.  By including [`<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#glEsVersion) in your manifest the [Android Market will filter out your app](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#manifest-filters) for users whose devices do not support OpenGL-ES 2.0 or better.

Comment: Even the very old G1 is upgradable to Android 2.2, the SDK version is not a reliable indicator of speed.

Comment: What if a G1 supports OpenGL ES 2? That doesn't really help me.

Comment: Then given all your constraints, unless you make your game run more efficiently, you're unlikely to find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

Before blaming the hardware you should have a good look at your code and do a few rounds of profiling and optimization. The questions you need to answer is which part of the code is causing the slowdown and why. On my old HTC Magic I've seen some pretty impressive stuff run fast and smooth, but I've also seen rather unimpressive stuff run very slow and jerky.

Requiring beefy hardware might be the quick and easy solution - if you can get it to work (see all the comments above) - but at the same time you'll miss out on a lot of the audience.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if this works:

add this to your manifest ( see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-gl-texture-element.html )

```
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="L_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1" />
```

This should filter out all devices that don't have a GPU ( since the software emulation will not support the texture compression formats above).

However, this is just a rough guess....

Comment: That would filter out ALL devices, because this is saying the device must support ALL of these OpenGL texture compression formats. None of them do. (For example, Tegra supports dxt but not pvrtc, whereas Kindle Fire and the other PowerVR devices support pvrtc but not dxt, etc.)